# Switch buck converters in series

Tags: power-supply, power, switching

I want to decrease a power line 1V below and because power efficiency and reliability is in top importance I chose to go with a switching buck converter.

I have  switching power supply that provides 5V and I want to connect one more in series to get 4V. What must I get into consideration to avoid unexpected issues?

Comment: Show shematic of what you intend to achieve. Your question is not clear.

Comment: *...I want to connect one more in series to get 4V* **Why** one or more in series ? I have buck converters lying around here that can take 5 V as input and directly output 4 V. How would there be a need to connect two or more in series ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1V voltage drop out of 5V implies 80% efficiency if you use a LDO regulator. So there's no need to use a SMPS for the secondary conversion.

Comment: It might if the output current is 10 amps because you can easily get buck converters that are 95% efficient. But I understand your point generally.